# How do I make a custom block with Minecraft Addons?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How can I add an entirely new block to Minecraft with addons, like mods on Java Edition?

Comment: I don't think you just saying this doesn't relate to Game Development is sufficient argumentation - *why* doesn't it relate to it? Your own answer seems to disprove it.

Comment: @Joachim okay I will try to explain. What do you think of when you think of game development. Someone using some quick copy-paste JSON for Minecraft Bedrock? No, if I called myself a game developer because I used a JSON API that would be just wrong. Same goes here. Game development is its own independent thing, whereas making a Minecraft block is in no way related to game development. There is not a **single line** of code that runs in this, so it has no code and no game. Also it shouldn’t be up to me to prove why something is **not** something, it should be up to the person labeling something

Comment: @Joachim do you have a response? Its still getting voted to close even though the only argument is that “my own answer seems ti disprove it.” I am completely fine if this is closed I just want to know *why* so me and others know for the future. Please?

Comment: Game development is not only about writing code. Doing game development-related tasks doesn't mean someone is a game developer (not only photographers post on Photography.SE, not only artists post on Arts & Crafts, &c.). It should be up to you to make a case for your question when a majority of (likely more experienced) users interprets it otherwise. Adding new content to a game is usually part of game development, even if it means only copying an asset and changing its properties and/or texture. ↴

Comment: Just compare [our Help section](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to [theirs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and see what would be a better fit. I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: @Joachim okay thats what I was looking for thanks

Comment: @Penguin do you mind if I add the related posts table from [my recent Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389720/how-can-i-create-a-minecraft-bedrock-edition-add-on) to this post so future readers can quickly navigate between these baseline posts?

Comment: @Tacoタコス but that puts it in the reopen queue unnecesarily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Requirements

- Windows 10
- Minecraft Windows 10 Edition
- I also recommend getting a new text editor other than notepad, I use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

## Before We Begin

- This answer assumes you know how to create a proper manifest, pack
  icon, and pack dependency linking.
- A rule of thumb for naming is use only no cap `a-z`, `_`, and `0-9` where the first character is not a number.

## Creating the Block File

Create a folder in your behavior pack called `blocks`. Then go into it. Create a `.json` file and call it what you want the ID for your block to be (Should use underscores `_` instead of spaces, also no caps). I have made a file called beige_brick.json.

```
{
    "format_version":"1.16.0",
    "minecraft:block":{
        "description":{
            "identifier":"msab:beige_brick",
            "is_experimental":false,
            "register_to_creative_menu":true
        },
        "components":{
            "minecraft:destroy_time":1
        }
    }
}
```

Open it in your editor and paste that. What did we do?

- `"identifier":"msab:beige_brick"` - I made a block with ID `msab:beige_brick`. The thing before the colon `:` is your prefix. This will be the unique prefix for everything new your addon creates. Make it whatever you want, as long as it is not `minecraft:`. The part after that is what our item's unique ID is. **The block's ID must be the same as the file name or it will not work.**
- `"minecraft:destroy_time:1"` - We have a destroy time of one. In the latest full release, tools cannot affect destruction time at all. This is one of many components.

## Adding & Registering a New Texture

In your resource pack, make a folder called `textures`. Then inside a new folder called `blocks`. Inside that put your PNG that you want your block to look like. Name it `beige_brick` (or whatever you made your ID)

- Default Minecraft Blocks are 16x16, although you can use any square size.
  Go back to your `textures` folder and make a JSON file called `terrain_textures.json`. This is where we will actually register our textures. In it paste:

```
{
    "num_mip_levels":4,
    "padding":8,
    "resource_pack_name":"msab",
    "texture_data":{
        "msab:beige_brick":{
            "textures":"textures/blocks/beige_brick"
        }
    },
    "texture_name":"atlas.terrain"
}
```

All that matters here is that `msab` is our prefix and `blocks/beige_brick` is our file path. Obviously if you used a different ID/prefix, change these.

## Resource Pack Texture Assignment

In your resource pack create a file called `blocks.json`. In it paste:

```
"format_version":[1,1,0],
    "msab:beige_brick":{
        "sound":"stone",
        "textures":"msab:beige_brick"
    }
}
```

We apply a sound and texture to our Beige Bricks. I set the sound to `stone`, but there are many others such as `metal`, and you can even add your own new sound, although I will not go over that right now. I also use the texture `msab:beige_brick`, which we registered before.

## Language Files

Language files is how we name our item, for example, a lit pumpkin is called a Jack O' Lantern.
Make a folder called `texts` in your resource pack, and in that a file called `en_US.lang`. In that put this:

```
block.msab:beige_brick.name=Beige Brick
```

We do `block.<prefix:ID>.name=<Block Name>`. Pretty easy.
I also like to copy this file and have a second called `en_GB` for UK English.

## We're Done

Try compressing and putting this into Minecraft!

Comment: it seems that this has broken in an update :(

Comment: I don't mind updating it if you don't mind me editing the post.

Comment: @Tacoタコスsure u can